# Firebase limited service account

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have a java client (Standalone app) that is using the Firebase Admin SDK, because I need to read values from the Realtime database whenever a value is changed. (A ValueChange listener is being used).

Currently I'm including the `service-account.json` in the app. Even if I set the roles to Viewer, using this `service-account.json`, I can create accounts using`FirebaseAuth.createCustomTokenAsync`, which is something I dont want.

Is there a way to make a service-account with Realtime-database read only?

I know I can use `setDatabaseAuthVariableOverride` to "limit", but if someone extracts my `service-account.json` from the app/jar, they have the power to do everything..

I'm not using node.js, just Java with spring. And js firebase is a no, because I need to receive updates even without a web page.

Comment: Custom token creation is a local operation and does not involve any cloud services. So there's no combination of permissions/roles that can prevent that.

Answer (score 2):

Never distribute service accounts to end users.  They should only go to trusted parties.

There is currently no fine-grained way to control access to Realtime Database via service accounts.  Access control is performed via [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) client libraries, which are not available for non-Android Java clients.

Comment: I see, any other suggestion? Because if I set the role to Viewer, the sdk won’t allow me to update a userrequest, but it still allows me to create custom jwt tokens..

Comment: If I had another suggestion, it would have been in my answer.  Essentially, what you're trying to do is not supported.